# Reactstrap dropdown opening multiples menu

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, reactstrap

Below is snapshot of my page:

[image]

I have used reactstrap dropdowns to bind the buttons with menu. Whenever I click one button all the dropdown menu are opening. Below snapshot is the dropdown issue:

[image]

Here is the code I have used:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import './Home.css';
    import { Dropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap';

    export class Home extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            let $this = this;
            $this.toggle = $this.toggle.bind($this);
            $this.state =
                {
                    dropdownOpen: false
                };
        }
        toggle() {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                dropdownOpen: !prevState.dropdownOpen
            }));
        }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="table-div table-responsive-xl">
                <table className="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" />
                            <th scope="col">Authentication</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.slackmembers.map((item, key) => {
                            return (
                                <tr key={key}>
                                    <td scope="row" />

                                    <td>{item.Authentication}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
                                            <DropdownToggle className="menu-button">
                                                <i className="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true" type="ellipsis" />
                                            </DropdownToggle>
                                            <DropdownMenu>
                                                <DropdownItem style={{ fontWeight: 500, color: 'black' }}>First</DropdownItem>
                                                <DropdownItem style={{ fontWeight: 500, color: 'black' }}>Second</DropdownItem>
                                                <DropdownItem divider />
                                                <DropdownItem style={{ fontWeight: 500, color: 'red' }}>Last </DropdownItem>
                                            </DropdownMenu>
                                        </Dropdown>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            );
                        })}                     
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I don't know whats wrong in my approach. Can someone help on this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a new component for Dropdown and manage the toggle state like:

```
default class TempDropdown extends React {

constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        isOpen: false
    }
}

toggle = () => {
    this.setState({isOpen: !this.state.isOpen})
}

render(){
    return(
        <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.isOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
            <DropdownToggle className="menu-button">
                <i className="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true" type="ellipsis" />
            </DropdownToggle>
            <DropdownMenu>
                <DropdownItem style={{ fontWeight: 500, color: 'black' }}>First</DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem style={{ fontWeight: 500, color: 'black' }}>Second</DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem divider />
                <DropdownItem style={{ fontWeight: 500, color: 'red' }}>Last </DropdownItem>
            </DropdownMenu>
        </Dropdown>
    )
}
```

}

and then Use it in your Home Component and pass the data as props (if any) like:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="table-div table-responsive-xl">
            <table className="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" />
                        <th scope="col">Authentication</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.state.slackmembers.map((item, key) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={key}>
                                <td scope="row" />

                                <td>{item.Authentication}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <TempDropDown />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}                     
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Hope this will solves your issue :)

Answer (score 3):

Every single one of them has the same prop:

```
isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen}
```

So when that boolean changes, it'll change the `isOpen` prop for ALL of them. Thus opening/closing them all. You need to track the open state of each individual dropdown.

(Also, you don't need `let $this = this;` in your constructor)

Comment: thanks but tracking the open state of each individual is very difficult as data is from database and the number of items won't be same always they can be even 100s of data.

Comment: Well then the easiest way would be to make a wrapper component for the dropdown component and have it manage its own state. Then you just write the component once and they'll manage their own open/close state, you won't have to track it in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use UncontrolledDropdown instead of the Dropdown component
https://reactstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/